# Ruby on Rails: undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, model, controller

I am trying to allow a user to enter a project into a database. One of the fields allows them to enter multiple technologies for that project.

Here is my project controller, new and create action.

```
def new
    @project = Project.new

@all_technols = Technol.all

@project_technol = @project.projecttechnols.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @project }
    end
  end


def create

    @project = Project.new(params[:project])

params[:technols][:id].each do |technol|

if !technol.empty?

    @project.projecttechnols.build(:technol_id => technol)
end
end

end
```

Here is my new project view for the multi select technology dropdown.

```
<%= fields_for(@project_technol) do |ab| %>

<div class="tech">
<%= ab.label "All Tech" %><br/>

<%= collection_select(:technols, :id, @all_technols, :id, :tech, {}, {:multiple => true} ) %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

At the moment, I have a page where the user can enter a new technology. But I want to move this option to the create new project page, where they can either select existing technologies, or enter a new one, or do both, and they would save with that project.

**EDIT: Change to question, plus adding of model files**

When I try to save a new project however, I am getting this error.

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Extracted source (around line #233):

233: <%= fields_for(@project_technol) do |ab| %>
234: 
235: <div class="tech">
236: <%= ab.label "All Tech" %><br/>
```

**project.rb**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :tech


  has_many :projecttechnols
  has_many :technols, :through => :projecttechnols
end
```

**technol.rb**

```
class Technol < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :tech

has_many :projecttechnols
has_many :projects, :through => :projecttechnols
end
```

**projecttechnol.rb**

```
class Projecttechnol < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :project_id, :technol_id

belongs_to :technol
belongs_to :project
end
```

**EDIT2:**

```
def new
    @project = Project.new

@all_technols = Technol.all

#@project_technol = @project.projecttechnols.build


@project_technol = Projecttechnol.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @project }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Ref [this](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference)

Change

```
@project.projecttechnols.build
```

To

```
@project.technols.build
```

Assumption you have following model declarations

project.rb

```
has_many :technols
```

technols.rb

```
belongs_to :project_id
```

Comment: Still doesn't work `undefined method technols for #<Project:0xafcef54>` :(

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't saved my models. thanks for helping. I have updated my question as now I'm getting another error. The create page now loads and I can select the technologies I have in the database, but now I can't save the project.

Comment: replace `@project_technol = @project.projecttechnols.build` with `@project_technol = Projecttechnol.new`

Comment: please mention the file name if it is ``projects/new.html.erb` then `new` method of the `project controller` should have above line.

Comment: See edit2. The error says `Showing /home/james/Desktop/webapp/app/views/projects/new.html.erb where line #233 raised:

undefined method model_name for NilClass:Class `

Comment: change `<%= fields_for(@project_technol) do |ab| %>` to `%= fields_for(@project.projecttechnols) do |ab| %>` hope that helps

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17234/discussion-between-jamesmcl13-and-salil)

Comment: I'm quite curious how the problem is solved finally cuz I'm seeing this error now...