# Nested form in simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm really new to RoR, and I'm trying to create a nested form using simple_form but I keep seeing this error turn up:

> NoMethodError in Forms#show
>
> undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass

I've taken a look at these links, but to no avail. I've also considered whether I have any typos, or have made a mistake about use of the singular/plural.

- [Creating multiple nested forms using simple_form and rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347450/creating-multiple-nested-forms-using-simple-form-and-rails-4)
- [How should I use rails and simple_form for nested resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436777/how-should-i-use-rails-and-simple-form-for-nested-resources)
- [Rails - Using form_for and fields_for, how do you access the sub-object while in the fields_for block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038341/rails-using-form-for-and-fields-for-how-do-you-access-the-sub-object-while-in)
- [Ruby on Rails: undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620206/ruby-on-rails-undefined-method-model-name-for-nilclassclass)

Here's my `_form.html.erb` code, the error seems to be coming from the first line:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@form, @customformd]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :legislation, label: 'Which Act?' %>
  <%= f.input :provision, label: 'Which provision?', collection: [ "Act A", "Act B", "Act C" ] %>
  <%= f.input :RB, label: 'Referring Body', collection: [ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"] %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Here's my `customformd.rb` code:

```
class customformd < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :form
end
```

Here's my `customformds_controller` code:

```
class CustomformdsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @form = Form.find(params[:form_id])
    @cformftcd = @form.customformds.create(customformds_params)
    redirect_to form_path(@form)
  end
 
  private
  def customformd_params
    params.require(:customformd).permit(:RB, :legislation, :provision)
  end
end
```

Here's a snippet of the offending part of the `show.html.erb` code:

```
<%= render @form.customformd %>
<h5>Add Custom Form D Specific Info:</h5>
<%= render 'customformds/form' %>
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NoMethodError in Forms#show
>
> undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass

You are rendering the `_form` partial in `forms/show.html.erb`, so make sure you have defined `@form` and `@customformd` in `forms#show` method like below

```
#form_controller.rb
def show
  @form = Form.find(params[:id])
  @customformd = Customformd.new
end
```

Also, the *class names* should start with *capital letter*(i.,e `customformd` should be `Customformd`)

```
class Customformd < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :form
end
```